# Honda Accord 2005 Headlight relay location

Tags: honda, accord, lights, relay

Side marker and full(high) beam working fine, but not dipped (low beam) headlights. Checked all fuses - ok. I looked at the cover of the fuse box above (pic below).

[image]
Honda Accord 2005 under-bonnet fuse box Lid

Which covers these fuses & relays:
[image]

The relays you can see only indicate fan controls, frost (!) and heating. Headlights are only shown in fuses F1,3,5 & 6 and as they are all fine I'm stumped what is causing the dipped main beam not to work. So I had someone switch the lights on and off from side to dipped main and a relay was clicking. Using feel I found the sound and vibration coming from the apparently sealed boxed section on the right of the bottom picture. After much wrangling, this covered portion of the fuse-box does not feel user-accessible even to replace a headlight faulty relay.

Q. IS the headlight relay inside this covered/almost sealed right side of the fuse box? If so how do you get to it?

(Bulbs are fine).

Thanks
J

Comment: According to my factory service manual, the relay is either in that box or that box is some kind of all-in-one inclusive relay. The manual does not give any details as to how to replace that part or diagnose a bad relay, at least not that I can find.

Answer (score 3):

The headlight control unit is in the sealed portion of the box.

It is a CAN network controller and not just a relay.

If it has failed the whole box is to be replaced.