# Highbeams on when car is turned off, DRL light on when car on and headlights off

Tags: electrical, honda, accord

I have a 2007 Honda Accord and, this evening when I got home form work and turned the car off, the highbeams remained on.  I didn't have the highbeams on when I drove home, but I did have the headlights on.  I started the car back up and when I released the handbrake the DRL light illuminated on the dash.  With the handbrake off, I turned the headlights on and the DRL light went out however the highbeams remained on and toggling them on or off has no affect.

My understanding is that the highbeams are run at half power to serve as the daytime running lights and the DRL light indicates a fault in that system.  I have tried removing Fuse 3 from the in-cabin fuse box as it's for the DRL system and it has no affect.  Removing the 2 fuses for the highbeams from the fuse box in the engine compartment will shut the lights off but the behavior of the DRL light on the dash remains unchanged.  It illuminates when the handbrake is released and goes out when the headlights are turned on.

With both highbeam fuses removed, if I release the handbrake and turn the ignition to postion II, the DRL light comes on AND the passenger side daytime running light (i.e. highbeam at 1/2 power) but not the driver side.  If I turn the car on and then turn the headlights on, the DRL light and the daytime running light go out.

My thought is that the relay for the DRLs might have failed on but I am unable to locate the relays for the DRL, headlights or highbeams.  The diagram for the relays in the fuse box in the engine compartment does not include any for the headlights or highbeams.  When I toggle the headlights on/off however I can hear a relay switching in the engine compartment.

Where are the relays for the headlights, highbeams, and DRL on a US 2007 Honda Accord?  I found some webpages on the Canadian version with an extra relay box for the DRL but my car doesn't have that.

Comment: This question shows the location of the DRL relays.       http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/13022/honda-accord-2005-headlight-relay-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that certain relays, like those used to control the headlights and highbeams are not serviceable. They are part of a Relay-Control-Unit (RCU) that is built into the under side of the Engine Compartment Fuse Box Assembly.  If any part of the RCU fails then you have to replace the entire Fuse Box.